# Call a javascript function with json_encode parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to call a function onclick, but with a json_encode parameter like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:table1Modif(<?php echo substr(json_encode($res['base']),1,-1); ?>);return false;">
```

And the Jquery function just alert the parameter:

```
<script>
    function table1Modif(key){
        $('#table1').html(function() {
            alert(key);
        }); 

    }
</script>
```

But I have an "undefined" error!
I am sure that it's due to json_encode, but I don't know how to solve it.
Thank you!

Comment: Where do you have an `undefined` error? What exactly does that error say? What does the HTML and the JavaScript look like? We can't tell what the PHP is going to generate.

Comment: The error appears in the console and says `'EAID_7F6C4CA4_984A_49e2_A138_73CEB37FDFF1' is undefined`, where `'EAID_7F6C4CA4_984A_49e2_A138_73CEB37FDFF1'` is the result I want to show in the alert. If I call `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:table1Modif(<?php echo $value; ?>);return false;">` it works because $value is not a json_encode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a string to `json_encode` in order to generate a JavaScript string literal (which is not valid JSON).

You are using `substr` to remove the quotes from this string.

JavaScript will therefore see an identifier (which in that context will be treated as a variable).

You need a string literal, so the first thing to do is **remove the substr call**.

This will create a new problem. You are inserting the string into an HTML document, but not expressing it as HTML. The `"` character at the start of the string literal will therefore be treated as **end of attribute value**, which you don't want.

When inserting non-HTML content into an HTML document you need to express it as HTML. Run the code through the `htmlspecialchars` function to do this.

```
onclick="table1Modif(<?php 
    echo htmlspecialchars(
        json_encode($res['base'])
    );
?>);return false;"
```

Incidently, I've removed the entirely useless [`javascript:` label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). You don't have a loop to `break` or `continue` from so it isn't doing anything. While you're at it, you should replace `href="#"` with something more sensible. Follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Perfect, patient, informative answer - thank you. I had the same problem due to my lack of knowledge - the MDN pages hinted at it being a quote issue but I ran out of skill when my escaping of quotes didn't fix it. StackOverflow/htmlspecialchars to the rescue!